# Open covering of Reals

Tags: general-topology

> Definition: Cover; Covering
>
> A collection $C=\left \{ U_{\alpha} : \alpha \in J\right \}$ of subsets of a space X is said to cover X or to be a covering of X, if the union of the $U_{\alpha}$ is equal to X.
> It is called an open covering of X if its elements are open in X.

It is claimed that the collection $C=\left \{ \left ( n-1,n+1 \right ):n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \right \}$ are an open covering of real numbers.

I attempted to verify this.

$C=\left \{ \left ( 0,2 \right ),\left ( 1,3 \right ),\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}$
Clearly, the elements in the collections are open sets.
The union of any open sets are itself open.
However, I am unable to show that the union of the elements in the collection equals to $\mathbb{R}$

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For any $x\in\Bbb R$, $x\in(\lfloor x\rfloor-1,\lfloor x\rfloor+1)$.

Comment: But $\lfloor x\rfloor\notin\mathbb Z^+$ if $x\lt1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of cover is incorrect. You only need $X$ to be contained in the union of $U_{\alpha}$.

Edit.: your collection does not cover the reals, since for example -1 is not contained in any of those intervals, as someone has pointed out.

However, if  $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, you can prove this using the [floor function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), which given a real $x$ outputs the largest integer $k$ such that $k \leq x < k+1$. If needed, prove why this function is well defined, i.e. every real has an integer part.

Comment: It seems to me that $\bigcup C$ is just the set of ***positive*** real numbers.

Comment: You're totally correct, I'm at my phone and formatting is kinda broken, I thought he meant $\mathbb{Z}$. Edited.

Comment: That is what I thought too-that the collection does not cover the reals since the open sets in the collection does not allow any negative elements which must be present in the reals. 
It could be that the notes meant positive reals.

Comment: Yeah that might be it, but you can be sure that this does not cover the whole real line.

Comment: I agree. That is why the reals is not a subset of the positive reals (all element greater than 0). And hence, C is not a cover of X= Reals

Comment: @GuidoA.
as an aside, why is the single-set collection {R} not an open covering of the real? Unless, again, if it should be "single-set collection of positive reals", then yes it does not cover the entire reals

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it definitely is. You can prove yourself that the reals are open. Trivially the union of the sets in the colection is just the reals, and $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I share your thoughts. The single set collection is just the reals. The reals is a subset of the reals. So the single-set collection of reals is a cover of the space of reals. 
There are some serious errors in my notes.

Comment: I'm afraid so. You can read about this online. Wikipedia, even though it is not the most formal source, has a good chunk of information on the subject. Good luck!